# What does the _ in [a-zA-Z0-9_] mean?

Tags: regex, perl

What does the underscore mean in the following regex?

`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

The `_` seems to make no difference so I don't understand the purpose of it.

Comment: BTW, `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` == `\w`

Comment: Please see [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) and [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html). Yes, I just said to "RTFM".

Comment: Tordek: \w depends on locale and also will match Unicode characters

Comment: There has been some talk of changing`\w` to always mean `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` for Perl 5.12

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It means to match the underscore character in addition to lowercase letters, uppercase letters, and numbers.

Comment: aaah its much easier if you just use a bit of your brain a-z   A-Z    0-9 :D

Answer (score 75):

The underscore means an underscore.

Comment: Try as a might, I couldn't find a single problem with your statement; it's utter simplicity and logic is beyond reproach :-) +1

Comment: How to get reputation Tutorial.

Answer (score 19):

Regular expressions are documented in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).  That's the place to check whenever you have a question about regular expressions. The [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) site is very helpful too.

To get you started, the thing you are looking at is called a "character class". Any of the characters inside a character class can match.

You can make a range of characters with the `-`, so `a-z` is any of the lowercase letters in that range. `A-Z` are the uppercase letters and `0-9` are the digits. The `_` is a literal underscore. Taken together those are the legal characters for a Perl identifier (variable names and so on). That's the `\w` character class in the ASCII sense (and not the expanded Unicode sense).

People often use that to match a Perl variable name but there's a rule that people forget. The first character of a user-defined name has to be a letter or underscore (not a digit). That means that you should use a different character class for the initial letter:

```
 [A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*
```

Comment: Thank you. Only if all of us were so tolerant of the newbies.

Comment: For someone new to regular expressions in Perl, I always recommend `perldoc perlrequick` first. It's a lot more friendly than `perldoc perlre` - mostly because it's not so overwhelmingly detailed.

Answer (score 16):

It means the underscore is also matched.

Answer (score 9):

With the exception of character sequences (`[.`, `[:`, and `[=`), range expressions (e.g., `[a-z]`), and the circumflex in the beginning (`[^`), **every** character inside a bracket expression means the character itself, just like that underscore.

As a side note, that expression is commonly represented by `\w` (word character, ignoring unicode and locale), and is commonly used to define the set of characters that are allowed to be used in variable names.

Comment: For most languages, `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*` is probably more accurate for variable names since they prohibit starting with digits.

Comment: And many languages nowadays allow other scripts for variable names as well. So Have fun with Unicode classes as well :-)