# Installing libxml2 on local machine

Tags: perl, libxml2

I would like to install [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) on my local Windows machine.

But I could not find any installation guide. Does any one know how to install `libxml2` in Windows?

The idea is after installation I would like to install [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML%3a%3aLibXML) Perl package.

Comment: Are you using ActivePerl? or any of the other Windows Perl packages?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970868/perl-installing-libxml2-in-windows

Comment: I am not using ActivePerl. Infact I dont have permission to install ActivePerl on the server machine. I only have CPAN command line utility.

Answer (score 0):

[Windows binaries for libxml2](http://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html) are available as noted on the [downloads page](http://xmlsoft.org/downloads.html).

Regardless of what's running on the server, you should give more information on what Perl distribution you have on your local machine. Did you compile your own `perl`? Are you running Strawberry?